# Binary File I/O. (feel like there's a a mental block with this operation)

Tags: c, io, binaryfiles

I'm supposed to make a C program which reads and writes binary files. It will takes 2 arguments:

1. the name of an input file (.wav)
2. the name of an output file (.wav)

I need to read the first 44 bytes of the input .wav file and write it to the output .wav file. However this is all new to me and I have watched several videos and still no luck in fully grasping the concept of buffers, shorts, size_T variable types.

Here's my problem, I understand that you need to initialize two pointers (input, output files)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv){

 if (argc != 2){
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <filename>\n", argv[0]);
    exit(1);
    }

  FILE *ipfile, *opfile;
  char *buffer;    //what does this even do? Apparently this is a block of memory that I will store what I read/write?

  ipfile = fopen(argv[1], "rb+");
  opfile = fopen(argv[2], "wb+");

  short first_44[44];   //i think this is where i'm storing the first 44 bytes?

  fread(&first_44, sizeof(short), 44, ipfile); //So i think that i'm reading from ipfile and reading up until 44 bytes and storing it in first_44 ?

  fwrite(&first_44, sizeof(short), 44, opfile); //I think this is just writing what was in first_44 to opfile

  fclose(ipfile);
  fclose(opfile);

  return 0;
  }
```

Anyone see what's wrong with this code and maybe help me better understand i/o (reading from a binary file and writing what you read to another file)

Thanks!

Comment: Did you read the documentation of [fread(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fread.3.html) and the other functions you are using? You really should **read the documentation** and compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`); you are using `fread` wrongly

Comment: A short is (at least) two bytes, not one, so your count (44 bytes) would be off.  You may want to use shorts later though, if you have 16 bit samples of endianess which matches your machine.

Comment: @ChrisStratton how would I ensure that only 44 bytes is stored in first_44? I thought the 3rd argument for fread/write was the maximum bytes you want to read/write.

Comment: @james: you thought wrong. Please read the documentation

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Ok I just read it and it's a lot clearer than the others i've read so thank you for that. Could you correct me if me paraphrasing of fread's documentation is correct?: "the first parameter is where I would store what i'm reading, the second parameter is the size of each element i'm reading, the 3rd parameter is the number of elements I want to read and the last parameter is what file i'm reading from" So would that mean that having first_44[44] as my ptr means that the 3rd parameter is irrelevant? and that even if I read the entire file, i'll only store the first 44 bytes?

Comment: The 3rd parameter is relevant, but you need it to be 1.

Comment: If you want to read 44 bytes then change `short` to `char` everywhere in your code. `short` is at least 2 bytes (maybe even more).  You aren't currently using `buffer` (and you don't even need it).

Comment: Unreated to the I/O, but you want to check that your number of arguments is three: the program name and the names of input and output files. As is, the name of the output file, `argv[2]`, is `NULL` at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Correct the code like.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *ipfile, *opfile;
    char *buffer;
    const int bytes = 44;

    if (argc != 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <filename>\n", argv[0]);
        return 0;
    }

//  open file
    ipfile = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    opfile = fopen(argv[2], "wb");

//  check if files opened   
    if (!ipfile)
    {
        printf ("Error opening input file\n");
        return 0;
    }
    if (!opfile)
    {
        printf ("Error opening output file\n");
        fclose (ipfile);
        return 0;
    }

//  allocate memory
    buffer = malloc (bytes);

//  read input file
    if (fread (buffer, bytes, 1, ipfile)!=1 )
    {
        printf ("Error reading input file\n");
        fclose (ipfile);
        fclose (opfile);
        free (buffer);
        return 0;
    }

//  write out
    if (fwrite(buffer, bytes, 1, opfile)!=1 )
    {
        printf ("Error writing output file\n");
        fclose (ipfile);
        fclose (opfile);
        free (buffer);
        return 0;
    }

//  close files
    fclose(ipfile);
    fclose(opfile);
    free (buffer);

//  success 
    printf ("Done!\n");
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: You need the `b` flag in the fopen flags

Comment: You should `free` the allocated memory and maybe also check the return value of `fread` so that you don't write uninitialised data to `opfile`.